# List does not exist error while using GetListItems

Tags: development, web-services, networking

I am trying get Data of a list using GetListItems Method of Lists.asmx
Here is my code:

```
XmlDocument objXMLDocument = null;

NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");                

XmlNode resultXml = null;

try
{
    XElement result = null;
    string strResult = "<Result>";
    ListService.Lists objLists = new ListService.Lists();
    objLists.Url = "http://domain:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
    objLists.Credentials = credentials;
    objLists.proxy=new WebProxy();
    objXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
    objXMLDocument.LoadXml("<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><Folder>" + "ListName" + "</Folder><ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\" /></QueryOptions>");
    XmlNode objQueryOptions = objXMLDocument.DocumentElement;
    resultXml = objLists.GetListItems("ListName", null, null, null, "100", objQueryOptions, null);
    XElement xresult = GetXElement(resultXml);
    XElement objXElement = xresult.Element(XName.Get("data", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"));
    IEnumerable<XElement> objXElementList = (objXElement.Descendants(XName.Get("row", "#RowsetSchema")));

    strResult = strResult + "</Result>";
    result = XElement.Parse(strResult);
    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
```

But it throws a Microsoft.sharepoint.soapexception and when I checked for details I got these errors:

*List does not exist.
    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
    0x82000006*

**Error XML**

```
<errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    List does not exist.
    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
</errorstring>
<errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode>
```

Sharepoint server we are using is not in our network, it is in our clients network and we use VPN for development.

I feel like the error is can be due to proxy.
In browser when i added the proxy provided by client I was able to access internet but not the sharepoint site,  than I selected automatically detect proxy and site appeared.

Also i find this link with same error but not able to understand what is suggested solution is.http://www.sharepoint-answers.com/microsoft/SharePoint-Development/29848065/getlist-wss-list-does-not-exist.aspx

Please suggest what can i do. or is it feasible?

Comment: What do you specify as ListName? It should be the GUID of the list. And I'd suggest removing the <Folder> element from QueryOptions

Comment: If it was the proxy you would probably get a 407 error. Since you're getting data back from the web services, you can connect OK.

Comment: How check for details for a Microsoft.sharepoint.soapexception and Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the list exists in the root of the site collection or in a sub site?

If the list is in the root than you can call it with:
http://yourserver:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

If the list you request is on a subsite you need to call the web service like this
http://yourserver:port/**SUBSITE**/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Comment: +1 this is what my guess was too.. `objLists.Url` needs to reference the actual site where the list exists

Comment: We are having a similar issue. A list with about 1200 items shows only 31 first items in a datasheet view with no Item Limit or Filter configured. ListData.svc renders all items, while Lists.asmx consistently limits to 31 and would not let you query for ID > 31 giving the same error as above.

Comment: As it seems, the problem arose after DPM restore of the list.

Comment: We had to do a delete/restore of the broken lists using a mix of Content Deployment Wizard to keep the GUIDs and web service based tools to restore the lists.